# How to call a function on button click in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a code in jQuery:

```
<span id="counter-up" class="timer">
</span>

<div class="buttons">
    <button id="trigger">Result!</button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
</div>

<script>
    var Numbers = 30;

    function secondPassed() {
        var random = Math.random() * 2024 + 10;
        random = parseInt(random);
        document.getElementById('counter-up').innerHTML = random;
        if (Numbers == 0) {
            clearInterval(countdownTimer);
            document.getElementById('counter-up').innerHTML = "2024";
        } else {
            Numbers--;
        }
    }

    var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 100);
</script>
```

In this code the function `secondPassed` is called as I load the page. I want that this function should be called when I click on button with Id `trigger`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind event on the element and pass the handler as the function reference

```
$('#trigger').click(secondPassed);
```

I'd also recommend to use non-string callback to setInterval function.

```
var countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 100);
```

1. You need to reset the variables to make the timer work
2. Don't use string version of function as callback to `setInterval` use function reference.
3. As you've included jQuery on the page, use it to manipulate DOM.

**Live Demo**

```js
var Numbers = 30,
  countdownTimer;

var $counter = $('#counter-up');

function secondPassed() {
  var random = parseInt(Math.random() * 2024 + 10, 10);

  $counter.html(random);
  if (Numbers == 0) {
    clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    $counter.innerHTML = "2024";
  } else {
    Numbers--;
  }
}

countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 100);

$('#trigger').click(function() {
  Numbers = 30;
  countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="counter-up" class="timer">
</span>

<div class="buttons">
  <button id="trigger">Result!</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    secondPassed();//after document ready
    $('#trigger').on('click',function(){
           secondPassed();//onclick of button
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    D = document

    $(D).ready(function() {

        $("#trigger").click(function() {
            var Numbers = 30;
            var random = Math.random() * 2024 + 10;
            random = parseInt(random);
            document.getElementById('counter-up').innerHTML = random;
            if (Numbers == 0) {
                clearInterval(countdownTimer);
                document.getElementById('counter-up').innerHTML = "2024";
            } else {
                Numbers--;
            }
        });


    });
</script>
```

I hope it works but all the answer are near that I think :D

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#trigger').on('click', function() {
            secondPassed();
        });
    });
    var Numbers = 30;

    function secondPassed() {
        var random = Math.random() * 2024 + 10;
        random = parseInt(random);
        document.getElementById('counter-up').innerHTML = random;
        if (Numbers == 0) {
            clearInterval(countdownTimer);
            document.getElementById('counter-up').innerHTML = "2024";
        } else {
            Numbers--;
        }
    }

    var countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed(), 100);
</script>
```

Comment: I want to do both thing when the page loads first time then it should work and after the button click this function should load

Comment: and also getting error in console secondPassed  not defined

Comment: ReferenceError: secondPassed is not defined